# Bootstrap 3 "fluid" footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a footer with bootstrap 3. In the end it should look like on this [site](https://www.nforce.com/).

I have already tried this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) but it is static and does not move with the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is static because there is no content to push the footer down, there's no scrollbar. That footer on the bootstrap site should work fine. I added a height 3000px to their h1 and the footer moved with the site.

Unless I'm confused and you don't want a sticky footer in which case this should work fine

```
.footer {
width: 100%; /* or whatever */
float: left; /* to clear it */
}
```

or

```
.footer {
width: 100%;
clear: both; /* to clear it */
}
```

Also be sure to add .container inside your footer div, then add your content inside the .container div. You content should then move 'with the site'

Bootstrap 3 doesn't have a set way of adding a footer, so go crazy. The only custom footer I can see from them is the sticky footer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing what a sticky footer is. A sticky footer is a footer that stays at the bottom of the content even at the bottom of the page when you don't have enough content to fill the page. It keeps the site looking neat and consistent.

What you are looking for is the **position** attribute. Set up the following class in your CSS

```
.fixed-to-bottom{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

add this class to the element you want to always show at the bottom of the screen.

I hope this helps.